# Excluding time of day from day of week in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to select data from certain days of the week, let's say Monday–Friday, but on Friday it needs to be BEFORE a certain time, let's say 4:30pm. This is pulling from years of data, so it's more of a filter on top of a date range. Currently the following is used to filter out only certain days of the week:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sometable
WHERE DAYNAME(created) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday');
```

But it needs to add a condition to NOT pull data that was created after 4:30pm on Friday. Something like:

```sql
DAYNAME(created) = "Friday" AND HOUR(created) <= 16 AND MINUTE(created) <= 30
```

With adding the above to `where` it will only grabs Friday's before 4pm and before 30 minutes of the hour.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Skip Friday in the IN list. OR the other condition, inside parentheses.

Comment: I'ts not "the problem", it's what you are rtelling the query to do, so you are the problem..  

WHERE DAYNAME(created) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday') OR (DAYNAME(created) = "Friday" AND HOUR(created) <= 16)

Comment: @MichalRosa Answers should be posted in the answer space, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to add a separate set of conditions for the Sunday. Also I would recommend using `WEEKDAY()` (the day number of the week, starting Monday), because that lets you shorten the query using comparison operator `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM sometable
WHERE 
    WEEKDAY(created) BETWEEN 0 AND 3
    OR (WEEKDAY(created) = 4 AND HOUR(created) <= 16)
```

If you want 4:30 PM instead of 4 PM, then you can use a slightly different approach and extract the whole time part of the datetime for comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM sometable
WHERE 
    WEEKDAY(created) BETWEEN 0 AND 3
    OR (WEEKDAY(created) = 4 AND CONVERT(created, time) <= '16:30')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was in the middle of updating my question to account for "minutes in the hour". Any ideas on how to update your solution to account for a "4:30pm" time

Comment: @doitlikejustin: I updated my answer for that use case.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I updated you answer to reflect WEEKDAY more appropriately since it starts at 0 and not 1.

Comment: @doitlikejustin: welcome, and thanks for fixing the query!

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this solve your problem?

```
SELECT *
FROM sometable
WHERE DAYNAME(created) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')
AND HOUR(created) <= CASE WHEN DAYNAME(created) = "Friday" THEN 16 ELSE 24 END;
```

Comment: Great solution, but how can this account for mid-hours such as 4:30pm (sorry, guess I should have specified this in the original question)